# how to add gzip middleware for the fastapi?

Tags: gzip, fastapi

```
app = FastAPI()

app.add_middleware(GZipMiddleware, minimum_size=1000)
```

I am trying to add fastapi middleware to gzip the responses as per [fastapi](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/middleware/#gzipmiddleware) the official documentation but my payload size is not changing.
Could you please tell me what am I doing incorrectly.

Comment: Are you sending requests that tell the server that you accept gzip compression? What does your requests (i.e. headers) look like?

Comment: Is your response very small? It will only apply gzip on leger responses.

Comment: I needed to add the headers, which was not obvious from the fastapi documentation. It is working as per my answer below. Payload size reduced by 90%. Thank you Mats and Jarro

Answer (score 2):

Adding the headers is the key.

```
headers = {"Accept-Encoding": "gzip"}
```

Sample API

```
@router.get("/test")
def test_handler():
    content = {"test1": 1}
    headers = {"Accept-Encoding": "gzip"}
    return JSONResponse(content=content, headers=headers)
```